# Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media after installing Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I have finished installing Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, and restarted when it told me to. When I restarted, my computer rebooted back into the USB drive, so I turned the PC off, took out the USB, and turned the PC on again. When I rebooted, I was greeted with a screen that said, "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media." When I got this message I decided to go into my UEFI settings and change the boot order so that it was 1. HDD/SSD 2. USB etc. I rebooted the PC and got the same message. **The computer didn't even show GRUB.**

After this didn't work, I decided to boot from USB again and look at GParted. When I looked at the resulting Partitions, there were only 2 partitions. One for System Recovery, and one for storing data. I didn't see any partitions that were for Swap and the like. Could this be the reason why the computer didn't boot into the OS? I also tried reinstalling the OS again to no avail. Should I have done a custom install and add all the partitions I needed myself?

As of now I am on my PC using Windows 10, because this the only OS I know that will work right now.

The computer used is a Toshiba Satellite C55-B. Dual Core at 2.16 GHz. 4 GB of RAM. 500 GB HDD.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 uses a swap file not partition as before...

Comment: I always do a custom partitioning, because it's a good practice to reserve partitions to /home, for example, in case of problems you will not lose personal data. Look https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: sounds like you installed grub to the USB instead of the HDD. besure that you are installing in EFI mode also. Use custom partitioning during install to verify that the installer is only using the ESP (EFI System Partition) on the HDD.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.